# How do get sections inside my TableView using swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I want to add sections in my TableView,

I have:

```
 var sections = SectionData().getSectionsFromData() // Declaration: [(key: String, value: [String])]
```

All my data stored in "sections". In the key stored all the ABC and in the values all the items that start with one of the 26 letter accordingly

I can't figure it out how to access the values

my code:

```
var sections = SectionData().getSectionsFromData()

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return sections.[section].count // error 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your dataSource is an array of tuples like this:

```
let sections: [(key: String, value: [String])] = [("A", ["Andrew", "Anna"]), ("B", ["Barbie", "Brad"])]
```

Then your `numberOfRowsInSection` method should look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].value.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sections is a dictionary of [String : [String]] and you are trying to index it with section which is an integer.  Instead you must index the sorted keys by the section, then use the correct key to index the sections dictionary.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let keys = sections.keys.sorted()
    let key = keys[section]
    guard let rows = sections[key] else {
        return 0
    }
    return rows.count
}
```